# ¿Como alinear los imputs que están dentro de un row para que tengan la misma proporción?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<form>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col sm-col-12 align-items-center">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="form-outline contenido col-6 sm-col-12  ">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-outline contenido col-6 sm-col-12">
              <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-outline contenido col-12 ">
            <label for="correo eléctronico">Correo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ejemplo@kittycakes.com">
          </div>
```

Los `input` del nombre y apellido se encuentran dentro de un `row` y necesito se alineen con los `input` de abajo.

También quisiera saber la manera para que, cuando se vea desde una pantalla pequeña, se muestre en `sm-col-12` ya que ahorita se muestra como en `col-6` aun cuando ya puse el código `sm-col-12` dentro de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

En Bootstrap 4 la clase "sm-col-12" no existe, en su lugar debes usar "col-sm-12", sin embargo para lograr el comportamiento que deseas debes invertir las clases, ya que "col-6" hará que el input ocupe la mitad del espacio disponible y no toda la pantalla.

Para lograr tu objetivo este ejemplo debe ser suficiente:

```
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-outline contenido col-12 col-sm-6">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-outline contenido col-12 col-sm-6">
                <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
            </div>
            <div class="form-outline contenido col-12 col-sm-6">
                <label for="correo eléctronico">Correo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ejemplo@kittycakes.com">
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

Saludos.

Comment: No me dí cuenta que puse la clase al revés muchas gracias